# {overwrite:true} in update query for mongoose statement usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Article.updateOne({title:req.params.aticleTitle},{title:req.body.title,content:req.body.content},{overwrite:true},function(err){}). What is the usage of {overwrite:true} ?

I just want to know that what is the utility of the same

Answer (score 1):

The `{overwrite: true}` option in the `updateOne()` method specifies that the update operation should replace the existing document with the updated document. In other words, the update operation will overwrite the existing document with the new document, rather than updating specific fields in the existing document.

This option is useful when you want to completely replace the existing document with a new document, rather than just updating some of the fields in the existing document.

Full syntax for the `updateOne()` method with the `{overwrite: true}` option:

```js
Article.updateOne(
    {
        title: req.params.articleTitle
    },
    {
        title: req.body.title,
        content: req.body.content
    },
    { overwrite: true },
    function(err) { /* Perform any necessary actions here */ }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If we have this article `Article { title, content, image }`

Overwrite will **replace document with update object**:

```
Article.updateOne({ title }, { title: newTitle, content: newContent }, { overwrite: true })
// Will remove image: Article { newTitle, newContent }
```

Without overwriting, **only properties in update object will be modified**

```
Article.updateOne({ title }, { title, content })
// Will not remove image: Article { newTitle, newContent, image }
```